# got 'Select' with DQL in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dql

I use Symfony3 and I don't know the matter with my code with DQL from a repository and I get this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 72: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

but I've followed instruction from anywhere. I don't know where the matter is? where is the problem?

```
namespace INSTAT\GPersonnelBundle\Repository;

/**
 * FonctionRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class FonctionRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
  public function getAvalaibleFonction()
  {
    $query=$this->_em->createQuery('SELECT f FROM INSTATGPersonnelBundle:Fonction f WHERE f.nbPlaceExige - (SELECT COUNT(e) FROM INSTATGPersonnelBundle:Employe e WHERE e.fonction=f) > 0');
    $result=$query->getResult();
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely Doctine DQL parser have no support for subqueries inside expressions, only inside joins. You need to remember that DQL is not an SQL and doesn't have support for all SQL features. Consider rewriting your query in a way that will exclude subquery from expression. In worst case you may need to fallback to native query usage.

Comment: Small detail, but change your quotes from `'` to `"`. Symfony use `'` for strings in query (and it's the norm in SQL), thus, you should use `"` for wrapping the query

Comment: #Flying, So how do I get it to the controller if I use native query usage?

Comment: #Preciel, I've tried it but it gives the same result